# How to gracefully stop nodejs server listener on macOS (mojave 10.14)?

Tags: node.js, macos

I am learning nodejs. I followed guide [here](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/getting-started-guide/) on official site and created app.js. This is a simple app that creates a HTTP server listening on particular port.

```
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  res.end('Hello World\n');
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

I am using macOS Mojave 10.14. I executed this through terminal, the server started listening. 
***Now there is no graceful way to get out.*** 
I tried,
 
1. process.exit() - No effect
2. Command + C - No effect (just error tone sound)
3. Command + D - Just sends the terminal to background but process is still running.
Only left with option to open new terminal and kill it with 
kill -9 PID or killall node. (This is not graceful way)

***Isn't there a graceful way to get out of this node process?***

P.S. Other problem is when you kill the process through other terminal instance the commands that are passed(options 1 to 3) when the server process was running are executed on the terminal where server process was started. e.g. 
1. term 1 -> server process started by node -> tried to close the process by options 1 to 3 listed above,
 2. term 2 -> killall node
 3. In term 1 -> server process died -> commands in option 1, 2 and 3 are executed. I didn't understand why this happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To terminate foreground process in UNIX systems, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>.  This should not be confused with the <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> key.

Comment: Got it. But is this the only way to exit the node process? I don't consider Ctrl+C a graceful exit.

Comment: Ctrl+c sends a signal (`SIGINT`) to Node asking it to terminate.  Making Node's termination more graceful, is up to the maintainer of the Node application, and requires the installation of a [signal handler](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_signal_events), which does whatever is necessary to make termination graceful.

Comment: i was tryin comand + C and it confused but this is the correct answer to my question:)

Answer (score 2):

***Dirty way***

`Ctrl-C` works just fine in my case (make sure your Ctrl is not mapped to something else: http://www.owsiak.org/macos-vim-modifer-keys-easier-life/)

[image]

***Gracefully***

**1. Package file**

```
-- 8< --- package.json -- 8< --- 
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js",
    "stop": "node app.stop.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "socket.io": "^2.2.0",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.2.0"
  }
}
```

**2. Application**

```
-- 8< --- app.js -- 8< --- 
const http = require('http');

const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3000;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  res.end('Hello World\n');
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});

const io = require('socket.io')(server);
io.on('connection', (socketServer) => {
  socketServer.on('stop', () => {
    process.exit(0);
  });
});
-- 8< --- app.json -- 8< ---
```

**3. Stoper**

```
-- 8< --- app.stop.json -- 8< ---
const io = require('socket.io-client');
const socketClient = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:3000/');

socketClient.on('connect', () => {
  socketClient.emit('stop');
  setTimeout(() => {
    process.exit(0);
  }, 1000);
});
-- 8< --- app.stop.json -- 8< ---
```

**4. Execution**

```
npm install socket.io-client
npm install socket.io
npm start

# in another console
npm stop
```